# NodeJS + TypeScript Error TS2339: Property 'timeOrigin' does not exist on type 'Performance'

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium-webdriver

I have a NodeJS/TypeScript app that uses Selenium WebDriver, which has approximately this snippet:

```
import { WebDriver } from "selenium-webdriver";

export class MyClass {
    public async getTimeOrigin(driver: WebDriver): Promise<number> {
        return await driver.executeScript(function () {
            // This should be the DOM's timeOrigin (same as if a person types "performance.timeOrigin"
            // into the Chrome DevTools console)
            return performance.timeOrigin;
        });
    }
}
```

When I attempt to build the above, I get the following error message:

> error TS2339: Property 'timeOrigin' does not exist on type 'Performance'

But it does certainly exist, since I can looks up the references on the `Performance` object and see `timeOrigin` inside. Can anyone please advise on how to fix this and correctly access the `timeOrigin` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`performance` is a global variable which is only available to the web browser you test. While you're working in NodeJS environment, it doesn't have any global `performance`, that's why Typescript cannot detect it and throw the error when compiling.

To fix this, you only need a simple global variable declaration:

```
declare var performance: any;
```

If you're using a lot of web interfaces in your Node environment, I recommend you import the lib `lib.dom` to typescript to avoid these types of errors:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

As mentioned by **mcernak**, another way is to use string as input to `executeScript` function.

Comment: Thank you. Here is what my `lib` already looks like: `"lib": [ "es2018", "dom" ]` so I believe `dom` should already be imported. What's odd is that this build issue only happens on Linux, but not on Windows. Do you know if `es2018` is somehow interfering with `dom` being correctly imported?

Comment: Also, to clarify, are you suggesting that I need to add `declare var performance: any;` and add import `lib.dom`, or should importing `lib.dom` theoretically be sufficient to fix this?

Comment: yes, in theory, just importing the line `"lib": [ "es2018", "dom" ]` can fix it. If you still have problem with it, try re-installing typescript or build project via local typescript: install local ts `npm install --save-dev typescript` and run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc`

Comment: `lib.dom.d.ts` already defined `performance: Performance` for you, if you use `lib.dom`, you will no longer need to declare `performance` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the compilation issues, you can provide the script that you want to execute in context of the browser as a `string`(instead of a `function`):

```
public async getTimeOrigin(driver: WebDriver): Promise<number> {
    return await driver.executeScript("return performance.timeOrigin;");
}
```

From the  [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#executeScript) of WebDriver.executeScript:

> Executes a snippet of JavaScript in the context of the currently
> selected frame or window. The script fragment will be executed as the
> body of an anonymous function. If the script is provided as a function
> object, that function will be converted to a string for injection into
> the target window.

Comment: Thank you for this option. I probably should have mentioned that the above is a brief script to reproduce the issue -- the actual script is much more complex. But I'll keep this workaround in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to cast it as `Performance`.

```
import { WebDriver } from "selenium-webdriver";

export class MyClass {
    public async getTimeOrigin(driver: WebDriver): Promise<number> {
        return await driver.executeScript(function () {
            // This should be the DOM's timeOrigin (same as if a person types "performance.timeOrigin"
            // into the Chrome DevTools console)
            const perf = <Performance>performance; // or "performance as Performance"
            return perf.timeOrigin;
        });
    }
}
```